# RESTful API in PHP for a script outputting in JSON format

Tags: php, json, rest

I am a PHP programmer and new to RESTful services. I have developed a page which outputs the data in JSON format, based on query parameters (_GET). Now I wan't to implement it so that I can call my script with different parameters via REST API.

My question is, how would I go about implementing the API in PHP. Basically, I am developing this so we can integrate the same data that is there on our website in a different interface for our client sites.

I already have most of data exposed in JSON format, just need guidance on how to implement the RESTful service for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_decode of php and you will get array.  You can use decoded array values for further processing. You can make a http post request or curl alternatively to make a rest request.

Answer (score 2):

are you comfortable with php frameworks? than you should give a shot to [laravel php framework](http://laravel.com) its is really awesome with low learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use Slim if you don't like Laravel for some reason. Take a look at https://github.com/victorjonsson/PHP-Rocker it will get you up an running in minutes